# Почему дублируются выводимые посты ? (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

Нужно на одной странице вывести посты из разных рубрик, но когда в коде указываю рубрику 2 и 3, то в них выводятся все посты из всех рубрик ? В записи  вопрдпресса, рубрики указаны правильно, в чём может быть проблема ?

```
                        <?php $top_query = new WP_Query('showposts=-1'); ?>
                            <?php
                            if ( have_posts() ) : query_posts('cat=2');   // указываем ID рубрик, которые необходимо вывести.
                            while($top_query->have_posts()) : $top_query->the_post(); $first_post = $post->ID;
                            ?>

                            <div class="news-item">

                                <a href="<?php the_date('d.m.Y' ); ?>"><?php  the_post_thumbnail('full');?></a>
                                <h4 class="ni-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
                                <p class="ni-desc"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                                <div class="ni-footer clearfix">
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="ni-more">читать далее</a>
                                    <span class="ni-date"><?php the_date('d.m.Y' ); ?></span>
                                </div>

                            </div>

                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                        <?php else : ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="middle-news-block clearfix">
                    <?php $top_query = new WP_Query('showposts=-1'); ?>
                    <?php
                        if ( have_posts() ) : query_posts('cat=3');   // указываем ID рубрик, которые необходимо вывести.
                        while($top_query->have_posts()) : $top_query->the_post(); $first_post = $post->ID;
                    ?>

                        <div class="middle-news-item">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                            <?php  the_post_thumbnail('full');?>
                            <h2 class="mni-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                            <span class="mni-date"><?php the_date('d.m.Y' ); ?></span>
                            </a>
                        </div>

                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                        <?php else : ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уже толком не помню, но вроде, вы или используете класс `WP_Query` или `query_posts` (могу не точно выражать мысль, поправьте если что не так) :

```
// Пример 1: Запрос с query_posts
query_posts( $args );
while ( have_posts() ) {
    the_post();
    the_title(); // вывести название
}

// Пример 2: Запрос с помощью WP_Query
$second_query = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $second_query->have_posts() ) { 
    $second_query->the_post();
    the_title();
}
```

[Картинка в тему](http://wp-kama.ru/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/avoid_query_posts.png)

По этому, в вашем коде необходимо изменить две строки:

```
$top_query = new WP_Query(array('showposts'=>-1, 'cat'=>'2'));
...
$top_query = new WP_Query(array('showposts'=>-1, 'cat'=>'3'));
```

Для указания множества категорий:

```
$top_query = new WP_Query(array('showposts'=>-1, 'cat'=>'2,3,4'));
```

или

```
$top_query = new WP_Query(array('showposts'=>-1, 'category__in'=>array(2,3,4)));
```

Comment: А если мне нужно вывести из трёх рубрик ?

Comment: В целом есть прекрасная документация где вы можете найти ответы - https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters Есть варианты: `new WP_Query( array( 'cat' => '2,6,17,38' ) );` или `new WP_Query( array( 'category__in' => array( 2, 6 ) ) );`

Comment: А можете мне помочь имплементировать это в код, а то я не совсем понимаю, куда это нужно вставить ...?

Comment: В чем у вас возникает трудность?

Comment: Не понимаю как ваш пример запихнуть в свой код таким образом, чтобы оно работало ...

Comment: Изменил ответ, надеюсь понятнее стало. Надеюсь что вы в состоянии найти две строки в коде и заменить. Первая часть ответа нацелена обьяснить причину почему не работает то что вы там написали.

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop#Exclude_Posts_From_Some_Category вот ссылка на вывод постов в цикле. В нём есть примеры, посмотрите примеры и сделайте то, о чем выше вам предложили